# Android - Java - missing Appbar after rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a detail fragment with the following method:

```
> @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID))
        {
            final Activity activity = this.getActivity();
            final CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
            if (appBarLayout != null)
            {
                int index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_ITEM_ID);
                appBarLayout.setTitle(getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE));
            }
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly when I enter the fragment, in normal or landscape mode.
Nevertheless, when I enter and switch the orientation the appBarLayout is always null.
What is the problem?

Additionally, this toolbar is always collapsed when I enter.
Is there a way to keep it "small" on entering and only collapse on scroll down?

Answer (score 1):

The fix for the "null" return has been to move the call to the appBarLayout from

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

to

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState)
```